# Getting a 0KB File in S3 when i write the zipInputStream

Tags: scala, stream

I have the following piece of code which is producing 0KB Files in S3 whats wrong with the following piece of code

```
def extractFilesFromZipStream(zipInputStream: ZipArchiveInputStream,
                                tgtPath: String, storageType:String): scala.collection.mutable.Map[String, (String, Long)] = {

    var filePathMap = scala.collection.mutable.Map[String, (String, Long)]()
    Try {
      storageWrapper.mkDirs(tgtPath)
      Stream.continually(zipInputStream.getNextZipEntry).takeWhile(_ != null).foreach {file =>

        val storagePathFilePath = s"$tgtPath/${file.getName}"

       storageWrapper.write(zipInputStream, storagePathFilePath)

        LOGGER.info(storagePathFilePath)
        val lineCount = Source.fromInputStream(storageWrapper.read(storagePathFilePath)).getLines().count(s => s!= null)
```

There is nothing wrong with the Storage wrapper, it takes an input stream and path and has been working well so far. Can anyone suggest what's wrong with my implementation of using zipArchive Stream.

Comment: What does `storageWrapper.write(zipInputStream, storagePathFilePath)` do?

Comment: It writes a 0KB file in the destination which is storagePAthFilePath

Comment: So is that what you wanted?

Comment: I think you are missing the step where you write the contents of the file to disk. What is the type of `file`? Does it not have an `InputStream` to read its content from?